# Determine the length of an audio recording?

Tags: audio, ipad

How do I determine the length of an audio recording I am recording programaticaly?  My current solution is to just time the start/stop recording events on the User Interface (literally the time the user hits record, then hits stop recording.)  Given a .aac audio file, is there some library call in Objective-C or Python to determine its length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the iPad:

```
totalFrames = format->mFramesPerPacket * recordedPackets;
lengthInSeconds = totalFrames / format->mSampleRate
```